# Most efficient way to get Least Significant not set bit and Most Significant not set bit

Tags: search, binary, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I have a binary string, say `10111101111` and I want the **Most significant not set bit** i.e the first 0 starting from the left and the **Least significant not set bit** i.e. the first 0 from the right.

Basically indices of these two 0s in: 1 **0** 1111 **0** 1111

I know the O(n) approach, is there a more efficient way to get these indices?

Comment: What operations do you allow? This would be easy if you allow operations like `lzcnt` and `tzcnt` (available in modern C++ via the `<bit>` header, in old C++ via compiler-specific means, and in various other programming languages but not all of them)

Comment: @harold I wanted to use it for competitive programming, so any operations permitted by the compiler of C++ on that website (codeforces in this case) works. Will give your answer a try, cheers!